# Does CM7.1 give a "low battery" alert?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, cyanogenmod, battery-life

I've been using CyanogenMod 7.1 since it became stable, and one feature I miss is the Low Battery alert. I've often come home from work, thrown my phone on the desk and forgotten to plug it in. When I try to check the phone for messages later, it's completely dead. The battery has run out with no warnings whatsoever.

On previous ROMs (stock and Darky's) I got a notification sound and a dialog that said the typical "your battery is running low" yadayada. Now there's not even a notification in the status bar.

Is this typical behaviour for CyanogenMod, or should I reflash?

Comment: I have 7.1 and I get it

Comment: I think it was in the settings somewhere ...

Comment: I get a notification in the status bar that it's low, but I do not get the dialog.

Comment: @Matthew Read: There's a setting for the sound on/off, but even though it's on, i hear nothing. It's the same with screen lock sounds.

Comment: @Ryan Conrad: I just get the notification in the lock screen, not even in the status bar...

Comment: @onik that could be where I get it, my phone is usually plugged in when ever i have the change, so it isn't very often that I get that notification.

Comment: Its in vanilla Android/AOSP in which this is derived from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summing up:** CyanogenMod from at least v7 up has, as usual, alerts for battery low. It can appear in different places:

- in the notification bar (Ryan Conrad)
- on the lock screen (onik)

I rawly remember even having seen a toast displayed. According to onik, there should be a setting somewhere to toggle the alert sound for this event on/off -- and according to [this CM Forum post](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/35286-no-notification-when-my-battery-is-low/)...

> Led lights are in CM settings, while low battery sound is in phone/sound settings.

I was able to find the sound at the end of the mentioned list with CM 7.2 (but not 7.0.3), but nothing in CM settings specific to the battery low event.

Though: If really needed, this should be quite easily established using Tasker...

Answer (score 1):

Usually it would alert you with a dialog. You may want to reflash your phone.